# Can't combine unallocated spaces

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, gparted

On my hard drive, I have ano extended  partition where I have 2 versions of Linux and some unallocated space. 
My problem is that the unallocated space is split in 2, and I can't combine them to make a partition for Ubuntu. One of them says unallocated  and 4.78 GiB and after showing other partitions, it says unallocated again, but with 7.42 GiB. I want to combine both of those volumes into one, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying those unallocated spaces have some partitions in-between? If yes - yo need to move them close to each other. In "gparted", the graphical interface for parted, there is a way to drag partition edges to move/resize them.

If you have multiple versions, you may need to boot into another one to move the first one's partition ;-). Or boot from the installation CD, it has parted too.

And ofcourse, if there is anything valuable on those partitions - back them up first.